# IOS AddressBook update contact or merge records

Tags: ios, addressbook

In my iOS app, I created my own contact form that appends to note an unique identifier for my app. I want to update the contact from address book as sql "update" statement.

In iOS i only see ABAddressBookAddRecord and ABAddressBookRemoveRecord methods. How can i do UpdateContact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our app, we let the user decide, whether to add a new contact or merge the new data into an existing one. We did it like that: (assuming you use a navigationViewController)

```
ABUnknownPersonViewController *view = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
view.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
view.displayedPerson = <YOUR-ABRecordRef-HERE>;
view.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
view.allowsActions = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

The user then sees the record in single view (just your "new" data) and has buttons to import or merge to existing contact.

Comment: i am not using navigationViewController. I want to synchronize phone contacts with server contacts, without loosing manually added fields through AddressBook. Do you know if is it possible to retrieve ABMultiValueIdentifier obj without delegate?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is possible to use `ABMultiValueGetCount` and then `ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex` which are described in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABMultiValueRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Finally i used the ABMultiValueGetCount method to iterate through all values in multiValue and compared my objects label with label constants. This approach did the job, but i consider it is  a little bit expensive. Thank you.